# Final window close event listener in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Multiple separate windows can be opened in chrome,

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId){ 
// action
});
```

Above code responds for any chrome window close event.
How to detect the last window close event or ultimate close event.
if not, is there method available to check any chrome window left active before handling close event.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

onRemoved:

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function callback)
```

Fired when a window is removed (closed).

getAll:

```
chrome.windows.getAll(object getInfo, function callback)
```

Gets all windows.

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function () {
    chrome.windows.getAll(function (windows) {
        if (windows.length <= 0) {
           // Write code here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please, describe the solution you are proposing rather than post only the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var openWindowCount = 0;

chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(Window window) {
  ++openWindowCount;
});

chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId) {
  if (--openWindowCount == 0) {
    // this is the last window.
  }
);
```

Not tested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sowbug ! If chrome doesn't run in background after last window exit, in that case above code won't work. My requirement is one such, user won't be running chrome in background after final exit.